# Ĉu mi povas diri "reigi" por esprimi "denove igi"?

Tags: word-usage, word-formation

Ekzemple:
Anstataŭ **"Tiu sperto denove igis min fortanima"** mi dirus **"Tiu sperto reigis min fortanima"**

Mi neniam vidis tiun vorton uzata. Ĉu ĝi ne estas ĝusta? Plue, temas pri poezia uzo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[En tekstaro mi trovas 3 uzojn de tiu verbo.](https://tekstaro.com/?s=65d8309ed43dc) La unua el ili

> La antaŭtagon, Josefino **reigis** la komunikaĵon inter la du ĉambroj, kiel ŝi […]

ŝajnas al mi en simila senco kaj strukturo, kiel vi celas. Do ŝajnas esti sufiĉe nekutima kombinaĵo, sed tamen kelk(maloft)foje uzita en literaturo.

Laŭ oni sufiĉe bone komprenas la celitan signifon / sencon.

> Plue, temas pri poezia uzo.

Nu, en poezio oni ĉiukaze rajtas preni pli da lingva libereco kaj eĉ ĉu poemo estu (laŭvorte) komprenebla (aŭ kiom laŭvorte komprenebla ĝi estu) estu decido de la poeto.